# How can I fix the vcr logo when it hits the corner?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm currently doing a school assignment, and it's consisting of basic Java graphics work. The code that isn't commented out makes the word VCR bounce around, like the dvd logo; except, when it hits the corner, it glitches and goes out of bounds by going back and forth while slowly moving up. It only does this when hitting the corner.How can I remedy this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent; 
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Movement_Assignment {
    int width = 800;
    int height = 600;
    int mouseX = 0;
    int mouseY = 0;
    class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    
        int xVel3 = 4;
        int yVel3 = 4;
        int xPos3 = 450;
        int yPos3 = 300;
        int xRadius3 = 225;
        int yRadius3 = 150;
        
        
        
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    
            /*
            Color purple = new Color(180,0,220);
            //Shape 1
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g.fillRect(200, 200,50,50);
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillOval(210, 210, 30, 30);
            
            
            
            //Shape 2
            
            Polygon shape2 = new Polygon();
            shape2.addPoint(400,100);
            shape2.addPoint(420,100);
            shape2.addPoint(420,160);
            shape2.addPoint(380,120);
            g.setColor(purple);
            g.fillPolygon(shape2);
            */
            
            //Shape 3
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            Font vcrFont = new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,50);
            g.setFont(vcrFont);
            String message = "VCR";
            g.drawString(message,xPos3,yPos3);
            xPos3 += xVel3;
            yPos3 += yVel3;
            
            if (xPos3 >= 800 - 100)
            {
                xVel3 *= -1;
            }
            else if (yPos3 >= 600)
            {
                yVel3 *= -1;
            }
            else if (xPos3 <= 0 + 20)
            {
                xVel3 *= -1;
            }
            else if (yPos3 <= 0 + 50)
            {
                yVel3 *= -1;
            }
            if (xPos3 == 780 && yPos3 == 50)
            {
                xPos3 -= 20;
                yPos3 -= 20;
            }
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            Methods.drawGrid(g, width, height);
            
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            frame.repaint();
            
            updateMousePosition();
            
            drawDirections(g);
            
            Methods.drawButtonPressed(g,width,height,mouseX, mouseY);
            
            Mouse.buttonJustPressed = false;
        }
        
        
        public void drawDirections(Graphics g)
        {
            
            g.setColor(new Color(40,40,40));
            g.fillRect(width/2,height,width/2,125);
            
            Font hudFont = new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,12);
            
            
            String display1 = "DIRECTIONS:";
            String display2 = "Move shape 1 right and left bouncing off walls.";
            String display3 = "Move shape 2 up and it should wrap around to the bottom each time.";
            String display4 = "Move shape 3 diagonally bouncing off all walls.";
            
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g.setFont(hudFont);
            g.drawString(display1, 400, height +30);
            g.drawString(display2, 400, height +50);
            g.drawString(display3, 400, height +70);
            g.drawString(display4, 400, height +90);

            
        }
        /*********************************************************
         ********* DO NOT TOUCH ANYTHING BELOW HERE!!! ***********
         *********************************************************/
        public void updateMousePosition()
        {
            Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(p, frame);
            mouseX = p.x;
            mouseY = p.y-30;
        }
        public DrawPanel() {
            KeyListener keys = new Keys();
            
            addKeyListener(keys);
            setFocusable(true);            
            
            MouseListener mListener = new Mouse();
            addMouseListener(mListener);
            setFocusable(true);
        }
    }
    
    JFrame frame;
    DrawPanel drawPanel;
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Movement_Assignment().go();
    }
    private void go() {
        frame = new JFrame("Movement Assignment");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height + 140));
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.pack();
        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't update the state within the `paintComponent` method and certainly don't use `Thread.sleep`! `paintComponent` is for painting ONLY. Use a Swing `Timer` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing is single threaded AND not thread safe.  This means that you shouldn't be blocking or performing long running operations on the Event Dispatching Thread and you shouldn't be modify the UI or any state it relies on from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

`paintComponent` is for painting the component state ONLY.  It should never update the state, block the current paint pass or trigger any other operations which might cause additional repaints (this will end in your CPU burning itself out)

In this situation, the best solution is to probably use a Swing `Timer`.  This will allow you to schedule repeated callbacks at regular intervals which are executed within the context of the Event Dispatching Threead.

See [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

Pretty much everything below...

```
/**
 * *******************************************************
 ********* DO NOT TOUCH ANYTHING BELOW HERE!!! ***********
 * *******************************************************
 */
```

is wrong.

Don't use `MouseInfo` to monitor mouse movement.  This is what a [`MouseMotionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) is for.

`KeyListener` is generally a poor choice for keyboard input and a preferred solution is to use the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which solves the focus related issues of key bindings.

This...

```
int width = 800;
int height = 600;
```

mixed with...

```
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height + 140));
```

is just a bad idea.  You're not taking into account the look and feels window decorations and "guessing" isn't it a good idea.  Instead, override the `DrawPanel`s `getPreferredSize` method and return the size you would the component to be, this way, you don't need to care about the window decorations at all.

Also, stop using hard coded values dimensions.  Instead, look at the actually size of the component and make your decisions based on that.

This will at least fix your animation issues, but you have a lot of other fundamental flaws which you need to address.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new DrawPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        int xVel3 = 4;
        int yVel3 = 4;
        int xPos3 = 450;
        int yPos3 = 300;
        int xRadius3 = 225;
        int yRadius3 = 150;

        private Timer timer = new Timer(15, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Dimension textSize = getTextSize();
                xPos3 += xVel3;
                yPos3 += yVel3;
                if (xPos3 >= getWidth() - textSize.width) {
                    xVel3 *= -1;
                } else if (yPos3 >= getHeight() - textSize.height) {
                    yVel3 *= -1;
                } else if (xPos3 <= 0) {
                    xVel3 *= -1;
                } else if (yPos3 <= 0) {
                    yVel3 *= -1;
                }
//                if (xPos3 == 780 && yPos3 == 50) {
//                    xPos3 -= 20;
//                    yPos3 -= 20;
//                }
                repaint();
            }
        });

        private final Font vcrFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 50);
        private final String message = "VCR";

        protected Dimension getTextSize() {
            // This could be cached
            FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(vcrFont);
            return new Dimension(fm.stringWidth(message), fm.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 600);
        }

        // Shouldn't be public
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            //Shape 3
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            // This is creating a lot of short lived objects and will
            // have an effect on the performance your program
            //Font vcrFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 50);
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(vcrFont);
            g.setFont(vcrFont);
            g.drawString(message, xPos3, yPos3 + fm.getAscent());
            // Don't update the state here, it's the
            // appropriate place
            //xPos3 += xVel3;
            //yPos3 += yVel3;
            //if (xPos3 >= 800 - 100) {
            //    xVel3 *= -1;
            //} else if (yPos3 >= 600) {
            //    yVel3 *= -1;
            //} else if (xPos3 <= 0 + 20) {
            //    xVel3 *= -1;
            //} else if (yPos3 <= 0 + 50) {
            //    yVel3 *= -1;
            //}
            //if (xPos3 == 780 && yPos3 == 50) {
            //    xPos3 -= 20;
            //    yPos3 -= 20;
            //}
            //
            //Methods.drawGrid(g, width, height);
            //
            // Oh dear me - no, no, no, no
            //try {
            //    Thread.sleep(10);
            //} catch (Exception e) {
            //    e.printStackTrace();
            //}
            // And no, no, no, no
            //frame.repaint();
            //
            //updateMousePosition();

            drawDirections(g);
//
//            Methods.drawButtonPressed(g, width, height, mouseX, mouseY);
            // This doesn't belong here
            //Mouse.buttonJustPressed = false;
        }

        public void drawDirections(Graphics g) {
            // Actually use the component size
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            g.setColor(new Color(40, 40, 40));
            g.fillRect(width / 2, height, width / 2, 125);

            Font hudFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 12);

            String display1 = "DIRECTIONS:";
            String display2 = "Move shape 1 right and left bouncing off walls.";
            String display3 = "Move shape 2 up and it should wrap around to the bottom each time.";
            String display4 = "Move shape 3 diagonally bouncing off all walls.";

            // This is getting rendered off screen
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g.setFont(hudFont);
            g.drawString(display1, 400, height + 30);
            g.drawString(display2, 400, height + 50);
            g.drawString(display3, 400, height + 70);
            g.drawString(display4, 400, height + 90);

        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            timer.stop();
        }

        /**
         * *******************************************************
         ********* DO NOT TOUCH ANYTHING BELOW HERE!!! ***********
         * *******************************************************
         */
        // This seems pointless and seems to be hacking around a problem
        // is more easily solved using a `MouseMoitionListener`
//        public void updateMousePosition() {
//            Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
//            SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(p, frame);
//            mouseX = p.x;
//            mouseY = p.y - 30;
//        }
        public DrawPanel() {
            // Bad idea
            //KeyListener keys = new Keys();
            //addKeyListener(keys);
            // Unnecessary if you actually used the correct
            // API - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html
            //setFocusable(true);

            //MouseListener mListener = new Mouse();
            //addMouseListener(mListener);
            //setFocusable(true);
        }
    }
}
```